# Different cosine similarity coefficients from Doc2Vec and Word2Vec

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, cosine-similarity, doc2vec

**BACKGROUND**

At the beginning of my project, the focus was to compare requests/questions received in terms of how they differ in terms of content. I trained a `Doc2Vec` model and the results were pretty good (for reference, my data included 14 million requests).

```
class PhrasingIterable():
    def __init__(self, my_phraser, texts):
        self.my_phraser = my_phraser 
        self.texts = texts
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.my_phraser[self.texts])

docs = DocumentIterator()
bigram_transformer = Phrases(docs, min_count=1, threshold=10)
bigram = Phraser(bigram_transformer)
corpus = PhrasingIterable(bigram, docs)
sentences = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(corpus)]    
model = Doc2Vec(window=5,
                        vector_size=300,
                        min_count=10,
                        workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
                        epochs = 10, 
                        compute_loss=True)
model.build_vocab(sentences)
model.train(sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
```

However, in a second stage, the focus of analysis shifted from requests to individuals per week. To measure how individuals requests differ from week to week I extracted all words from requests in a given week t and compared with all words from requests in the previous week t-1 using `d2v_model.wv.n_similarity`. Since I need to replicate this in other areas, occurred to me that I was wasting to much memory and time training `Doc2Vec` models when I could use `Word2Vec` to get the same measure. Thus, I trained the following `Word2Vec` model:

```
docs = DocumentIterator()
bigram_transformer = gensim.models.Phrases(docs, min_count=1, threshold=10)
bigram = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(bigram_transformer)
sentences = PhrasingIterable(bigram, docs)
model = Word2Vec(window=5,
                        size=300,
                        min_count=10,
                        workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
                        iter = 10, 
                        compute_loss=True)
model.build_vocab(sentences)
model.train(sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
```

I used again the cosine similarity to compare the content from week to week `w2v_model.wv.n_similarity`. As a sanity check, I compared the similarities generated by `Word2Vec` and `Doc2vec`, the correlation coefficient among is around 0.70 and the scale differs a lot. My implied assumption is that comparing sets of extracted words using `d2v_model.wv.n_similarity` was taking advantage of the `Word2Vec` within the trained `Doc2Vec`.

**MY QUESTION**

Should cosine similarity measures between two sets of extracted words differ as we trade from `Doc2Vec` to `Word2Vec`? If so, why? I not, any suggestions on my code?

Comment: just a guess but cosine similarity is just dot product under disguise. If two libraries are using different vectors for the groups, it seems natural that their results would differ

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by comparing weeks - how many weeks? Are they per person per week? How many words are in each text for comparison. Also, it's not clear how you'd use `Word2Vec` alone to compare similarity of multi-word texts. (Word2Vec only creates vectors per word, so you could compare words. There are a variety of ways to perhaps then use those word-vectors in larger comparisons, but no one that's so dominant it can be assumed without specification.)

Comment: Also, it's a bit odd that for your `Word2Vec` model, you changed a bunch of defaults you left unchanged for `Doc2Vec`. Why a non-default `sample` for one but not the other? Why a non-default  starting `alpha` for one buut not the other? Why a non-default `window` for one and not the other?

Comment: I'm sorry @gojomo for the missing info. I am comparing person per week over 5 years and each request has on average 100 words. I corrected the code provided, I tried to adjust the specifications to improve the `Doc2Vec` model but even using similar specifications the differences persist. Also `n_similarity(ws1, ws2)` from `Doc2Vec` compute the cosine similarity between two sets of words, thus, between requests from week1 and week2, in my case. If I did not understand your questions, please let me know.

Comment: Were you in fact using `d2v_model.wv.n_similarity()` (and not anything based on doc-vectors) in the earlier requests-only case (not involving per-user-per-week pseudodocuments), when the results were "pretty good"? Can you be more specific about any differences in usefulness you've seen between using (A) original `Doc2Vec` model; (B `Word2Vec` model as originally in your question, with a number of not-clearly-motivated parameter changes; (C) `Word2Vec` model in your updated question with parameters more similar to original `Doc2Vec`? (Or are they all equally bad on the new user-week task?)

Comment: 1) My results were clearly good at first stage of the project, when I was using `Doc2Vec` as originally designed: measuring the distance between two documents. 2) In terms of usefulness, the `n_similarity()` measure of pseudodocuments makes sense for both `Word2Vec` and `Doc2Vec` in my tests, I am mostly worried because they less correlated than I expected (0.70)  3) The adjusments in the parameters of the `Word2Vec` do not changed the model, the results were almost identical between `Word2Vec` C and variations of `Word2Vec` B.

Comment: Well, using `n_similarity()` between lists-of-words is a very different comparison than doc-vectors. If you think it's adequate, you could try it in your original 1st phase, too, instead of doc-vectors. Does it work well there? If not, it shouldn't be a surprise that `n_similarity` comparisons reflect different things, report different closest-neighbors, & show a different scale. If `n_similarity` worked the same (& as well in all cases) there'd be no reason for the different `Doc2Vec` algorithm at all.

Comment: Since your `Doc2Vec` model (A) also includes word-vecs, it's be interesting to see if your `n_similarity` results from it are also like those from pure `Word2Vec` models. I suspect they are, except for small amounts of run-to-run jitter, becase: whenever a `Doc2Vec` mode has word-vecs, they're trained in the exact same way as `Word2Vec`, and indeed word-to-word contexts often far outnumber doc-to-word contexts, so the model is still, mostly, a W2V model. (The training of doc-vecs isn't an especially time-consuming added final step, but something that happens alongside word-vecs the whole way.)

Comment: So: not surprising `n_similarity` mean-of-word-vector results would have only partial correlation & scale-similarity to doc-vector results. You could also try `n_similarity` on your original task to see if it was adequate there. You could also try training actual doc-vectors for a unique id-tag for each user-week pseudodocument. To the extent this would be more like your earlier step, you might find more comparable results. Indeed, if these pseudodocs are trained in the same session as your earlier docs, they'll have vectors in the same coordinate space.

Comment: @gojomo that is exactly the reason for my question: since my `Doc2Vec` model (A) also includes word-vecs, the `n_similarity` results from it should be like those from pure `Word2Vec` models. Like you, I suspected they should be quite similar, however, they have only a partial correlation (0.70). I am not a native speaker, I am sorry I could not be clearer in my question.

Comment: No worries! Your English is excellent & I don't think it's language that's slowed my understanding as much as domain lingo. It wasn't clear you were in fact using `n_similarity` comparisons from `Doc2Vec` on 1st problem, as opposed to trained doc-vectors and/or `infer_vector` doc-vectors.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how you're calculating the 0.7 correlation. (If you wanted to dive-deeper, showing the code for that calc might help.) But, you might similarly see a less-than-expected correlation from just random jitter between retraining exact same model, for example w/ changed initial seeds and/or the other random influence of threading ordering, Too much such jitter from run-to-run on exact same data/parameters could indicate other suboptimal parameters, risking either under-training or overfitting.

Comment: @gojomo to get this correlation, I just picked 1000 random pairs of documents to measure the `n_similarity` using both `Doc2Vec` and `Word2Vec`, then I calculate the pairwise correlation between the two measures. Also, thank you for the tip, I will check for under-training or overfitting.